# The degree (measure) of $\mathbb R^n$ angles?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let closed connected set $M\subset S^2$ where $S^2$ is a unit sphere. Connecting the points $p\in brdy(M)$ with the origin $O$. we call this object, $OM$, a 3-D angle, visually. We define the "degree" of such angle by the surface area of $M$.

E.g. if the area $A(M)=4\pi$, the $OM$ is a full angle (360).

One could verify that the sum of interior (n-dimensional) angles of n-dimensional cube is always 360 degrees.

---

Are there any literature extend this definition

I have never learnt this in geometry class. Update: After some research I find the name of such angle is "solid angle".

Comment: Only in two dimensions are angles measured in "degrees".   For example angles in 3 dimensions are usually measured in "steradians".  There are $4\pi$ steradians in an entire sphere.  Occasionally you will see space angles measured in "square degrees".  There are approximately 41254 "square degrees" in an entire sphere.  But angles in higher dimensions are simply not measured in "degrees"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) (although usually not normalized to $360 ^\circ$.)